# How do I set an iCloud e-mail?

Tags: icloud, email, ipod-touch

When I first got my iPod I was given the option to set up an iCloud address. At the time I didn't want one; however, I want one now. So, how do I get one now?

Comment: Perhaps try: Settings > iCloud for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to **Settings** > **Mail, Contacts, Calendars** > **Add Account**, then choose **iCloud**. At the bottom of the next screen you'll see **Get a Free Apple ID**.

[image]